# VS2015: Missing Debug targets for TACO

Tags: android-emulator, visual-studio-cordova

I'm using VS2015 and just updated the Visual Studio Android Emulator  (to 1.1.622.2) this morning. Since I've done so, the debug targets have disappeared for all of my TACO projects (the drop-down is empty for all device types, incl. Android and iOS):

[image: Missing Debug Targets]

I have followed the instructions [here](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tips-and-workarounds-general-readme/#unable-to-start-debugging), but no CoreCon folder is recreated when I re-build. The build does succeed (i.e. I get an .apk file that works) but I can't deploy to any emulator or local device from Visual Studio. The emulator itself works fine.

Any ideas? I've tried rebuilding the Cordova cache but with no success.

Comment: What build/update of VS2015 are you using? It looks like a package didn't load when you updated VS. Repairing VS should add the Android targets back into their dropdown. 

Also, is this behavior just for Android?

Comment: Version 14.0.25425.01 Update 3. This was for both Android and iOS. Repairing VS didn't help, but I just installed the update to VS SQL Server Data Tools and it fixed it... :S No idea why.